# Convert characters like "84+3" into numeric variables using R

Tags: r

I have a large `data.frame` with several variables like "89+2" (all two-digit integer + one-digit integer) and I'm trying to quickly convert to numeric variables. Realistically, either just eliminating the second numeric OR performing the calculation and adding them together would work... Bit of an R newbie. Any help appreciated.

example:

```
df$LM = c("91+2", "89+3", "88+2")
```

Looking for

```
df$LM_num = c(91, 89, 88)
```

or

```
df$LM_num = c(93, 92, 90)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
separate(df, LM, into = c("LM_num1", "LM_num2"), convert = TRUE) %>%
        mutate(LM_num = LM_num1 + LM_num2)
```

Or with `parse_number`

```
library(readr)
df$LM_num <- parse_number(df$LM)
```

---

Or another option is `eval(parse`

```
df$LM_num <- sapply(df$LM, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` given reproducibly in the Note at the end use the first line below to get the first number or the second line to get the sum.  They both read the `LM` column as if it were a file splitting on `+` creating a two column data frame.  The first line extracts the first column whereas the second line adds the two columns. No packages are used.

```
transform(df, LM_num = read.table(text = LM, sep = "+")[[1]])
transform(df, LM_num = rowSums(read.table(text = LM, sep = "+")))
```

### Note

```
df <- data.frame(LM = c("91+2", "89+3", "88+2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
x <- '92+3'    
sum(as.numeric(strsplit(x, split = '+',fixed = TRUE)[[1]]))
```

In case of having a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(LM = c("91+2", "89+3", "88+2"))

df$sum <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), 
                 function(i) sum(as.numeric(strsplit(df$LM, split = '+', fixed = TRUE)[[i]])))

#     LM sum
# 1 91+2  93
# 2 89+3  92
# 3 88+2  90
```